# Explanation of this (probably very easy) derivation using conditional expectation

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation

In my lecture notes there is written an equation

$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1} \mid X_t =x ] \leq (1-\delta) x,$$

(how this equation is derived, does not really matter here).

Then the next part is:

"Taking the expectation on both sides,

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1} \mid X_t ] \mid X_0 = s_0] \leq (1-\delta) \mathbb{E}[X_t \mid X_0 = s_0]. \quad  (1)$$

By the definition of a conditional expectation, we have

$$\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1} \mid X_0 = s_0]= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1} \mid X_t ] \mid X_0 = s_0], \quad (2)$$

so

$$ \mathbb{E}[X_{t+1} \mid X_0=s_0] \leq (1-\delta) \mathbb{E}[X_t \mid X_0 = s_0]." \quad (3)$$

So I am really confused about this derivation and need some help further explaining these steps. The step from (2) to (3), however, is obvious, since it is only putting (1) into (2). I am a beginner in working with conditional expectations, so this is probably why I have no idea how to tackle such a problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Edit: Maybe one sentence about what confuses me the most: Taking the conditional expectation (conditioned on $X_0=s_0$) seems to be legit, but why does the conditioning on $X_t=x$ (in the first equation) disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first (un-numbered) inequality is valid for every possible value $x$ of $X_t$. If so, then the inequality is valid for $X_t$ itself:
$$ E(X_{t+1}|X_t) \le (1-\delta)X_t\tag0$$
That's how the conditioning on $X_t=x$ disappeared; it was replaced by the above statement about $X_t$, omitted from your lecture notes, which I've labeled ($0$).

Line ($1$) is a straightforward application of $E(\cdots|X_0=s_0)$ to both sides of ($0$). Line ($2$) follows from the def of conditional expectation because $\sigma(X_0)$ is a coarser $\sigma$-algebra than $\sigma(X_t)$ (the "tower" property of conditional expectation).

Comment: Thank you very much. This explains everything and is now clear to me. Also thanks for mentioning the name of this tower property, now I know what I have to learn/repeat in order to understand similar derivations, so I'll have a look at the properties of conditional expectation. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I posted a question concerning this power property here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1158742/probability-space-and-conditioning-simple-questions?noredirect=1#comment2362983_1158742) and got the answer that this is not correct. I must misunderstand something and I would really appreciate if you could help me here!

Comment: The remarks under your second question are correct: the tower property holds if $\sigma(X_0)$ is contained in $\sigma(X_t)$, which I was assuming to be true in your example. Can you provide additional information about the what the $\{X_t\}$ represent?

Comment: We are considering for example the Coupon Collector problem, where we want to collect $n$ different types of coupons. In every step $t$ we draw one of the $n$ coupon types uniformly at random and $X_t$ denotes the number of coupon types missing until we have all types. Hence $X_t$ is monotonically decreasing, non-negative. So $X_0$ in this example would be $n$ and $X_t \in \{0, \dotsc, n \}$.

Comment: So $\sigma(X_0)$ is the $\sigma$-algebra where we condition on the value of $X_0$, namely, $X_0=n$, and  $\sigma(X_t)$ would be the $\sigma$-algebra with $X_t = a$ for some $a\leq n$. So I would say neither $\sigma(X_0) \subseteq \sigma(X_t)$ nor vice versa, or could you help me with this using an "intuitive" argument?

Comment: This is useful information because $X_0$ is _constant_, so $\sigma(X_0)$ is a trivial sigma-field (it consists of the empty set and the entire space), hence it is indeed contained within $\sigma(X_t)$ for every $t$, so we're good to apply the tower property.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much! So since we have $X_0=n$, $\sigma(X_0)$ just can differentiate between "all" and "nothing" and $\sigma(X_t)$ additionally requires that $X_t = x$ for some $x$. Hence $\sigma(X_t) \subseteq \sigma(X_0)$ and we can apply a variant of the tower property that says

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y] \mid Z] = \mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]$, if $\sigma(Y) \subseteq \sigma(Z)$.

Is this correct? Do you have an intuitive explanation why the coarser sigma-algebra remains? Intuitively I would say, we need to condition on more information, hence on the "finer" sigma-algebra.

Comment: The intuition is that conditional expectation is a coarsening operation on a random variable. Conditioning on a smaller (coarser) sigma-algebra forces the result to be more discretized (in the extreme case, the result is constant), while conditioning on a finer sigma algebra allows more of the original random variable to be "retained" (in the extreme case, $X$ is unchanged). In general if $\mathcal G$ and $\mathcal F$ are sigma-algebras with $\mathcal G\subset\mathcal F$, then the coarser sigma-algebra prevails: $E(E(X|\mathcal G)|\mathcal F) = E(E(X|\mathcal F)|\mathcal G) = E(X|\mathcal G)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was very helpful and I think I finally got it!